# Command history in AIX not found

Tags: unix, aix

I enter:

```
# history
```

And AIX comes back with:

```
history: not found.
```

What am I missing? Do I need to configure something before I can use the history command?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AIX, but what's your shell (echo $SHELL)? If it's the Bourne shell (plain sh), you won't have that command available.

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, voting to move to http://superuser.com/  OR you can 'flag' it and ask for a moderator to move it. (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Comment: You need to choose a shell that supports `history`.  The standard `/bin/sh` command does not support it.  Use `ksh` or `bash` (the latter can be added if necessary) instead.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys I was messing around changing shells trying to get what I wanted and thought I was still in ksh because at the level I was using it ... it behaves the same as bsh.   I switched it back to ksh and surprise surprise it work!   I've settled into ksh with vi now.   No pointing in laming out with arrow keys :-)

Comment: You can try this combination: 'bash' as the interactive shell, and 'ksh' for scripts (this way you don't need to worry about setting the arrow-keys and you can easily see the last commands that were run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to agree with the two comments to your question, but here is your answer anyhow, courtesy of IBM:

[Listing previously entered commands (history command)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/listing_prev_cmds.htm)

In short:

- The history command is a **Korn shell built-in command** that lists the last 16 commands entered.
- The **Bourne shell** *does not support* command history.

Good luck!

Comment: Pretty sad but I was in fact using Bourne shell.  I guess the answer is 'check your shell.'   Thanks @jmdeldin too